# my program after work correct generate random segment fault

Tags: c, scanf

[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3K8a.jpg)
i try to made one simple life simulator program , for more than
9000 steps anything work good , but when im near to get the last survive , when still have 3 or 4 of them , come out segmentation fault , not at the start of the program but after the program ready worked for long time . i try to check the error and look like something wrong with sscanf  int the code below .
if someone can help me ill be so grateful cause i tried ready anything i know  for track the problem.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

void newborn();
void attack();
int rnd();
void life();
char animals[100][100];

typedef struct {
    int no;
    char name[30];
    int fast;
    int life;
    int streng;
    int age;
} creature;

int
main()
{
    rnd();
    newborn();
    life();
}

void
newborn()
{
    char name[30];
    creature creat;

    rnd();
    for (int x = 0; x <= 99; x++) {
        sprintf(name, "REX");
        strcpy(creat.name, name);
        creat.no = x;
        creat.age = 0;
        creat.fast = rand() % 100;
        creat.life = 10;
        creat.streng = rand() % 100;;
        sprintf(animals[x], "%03d\t%s\t%03d\t%03d\t%03d\t%03d\n", creat.no, creat.name, creat.age, creat.fast, creat.life, creat.streng);
    }
}

void
attack()
{

    creature creat;
    creature creat1;
    int rnd;
    int rnd1;

    rnd = rand() % 100;
    rnd1 = rand() % 100;
    if (rnd == rnd1) {
        life();
    }

    sscanf(animals[rnd], "%03d\t%s\t%03d\t%03d\t%03d\t%03d\n", &creat.no, creat.name, &creat.age, &creat.fast, &creat.life, &creat.streng);
    if (creat.life == 0) {
        life();
    }

    sscanf(animals[rnd1], "%03d\t%s\t%03d\t%03d\t%03d\t%03d\n", &creat1.no, creat1.name, &creat1.age, &creat1.fast, &creat1.life, &creat1.streng);
    if (creat1.life == 0) {
        life();
    }

    if (creat.fast > creat1.fast) {
        if (creat.streng > creat1.streng) {
            creat.life++;
            creat.streng++;

            creat1.life--;
            // creat1.streng--;
        }
        if (creat.streng < creat1.streng) {
            creat.life--;
            // creat.streng++;

            creat1.life++;
            creat1.streng++;
        }
        if (creat.streng == creat1.streng) {
            creat.life--;

            creat1.life--;

        }
    }

    if (creat.fast < creat1.fast) {

        creat.life--;
        creat1.life--;
    }
    if (creat.fast == creat1.fast) {

        creat.life--;
        creat1.life--;
    }

    system("clear");
    // creature zero

    printf("\n NO %03d \n NAME %s\n AGE %d\n FAST %d\n LIFE %d\n STRENG %d\n ", creat.no, creat.name, creat.age + 1, creat.fast, creat.life, creat.streng);

    sprintf(animals[rnd], "%03d\t%s\t%03d\t%03d\t%03d\t%03d\n", creat.no, creat.name, creat.age + 1, creat.fast, creat.life, creat.streng);

    // creature one

    printf("\n NO %03d \n NAME %s\n AGE %d\n FAST %d\n LIFE %d\n STRENG %d\n ", creat1.no, creat1.name, creat1.age + 1, creat1.fast, creat1.life, creat1.streng);

    sprintf(animals[rnd1], "%03d\t%s\t%03d\t%03d\t%03d\t%03d\n", creat1.no, creat1.name, creat1.age + 1, creat1.fast, creat1.life, creat1.streng);
}

int
rnd()
{
    srand(time(0));
    return 0;
}

void
life()
{

    while (1) {
        attack();
        usleep(20000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered running it in a debugger to see where it crashes? Since `life()` is an endless loop I'd guess you're eventually running into a stack overflow. Is there a good reason you're not using an array of `creature` instead of converting to and from strings? The string conversion seems like a terrible idea to me.

Comment: In your previous post (now deleted) of the same question you were requested to use a debugger and to post at least the stack trace when the seg fault occurs. Why haven't you done that? If not for Stack Overflow then for yourself as that is minimal and crucial debugging info.

Comment: i did it but because in not so expert and still learning i trying to find the way for show you .Cause i get it in terminal using gdb

Comment: If it is a normal terminal then just select the terminal output, copy it and paste it directly into the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might be blowing your stack. The functions `life()` and `attack()` call each other - eventually the program will run out of stack, and attempts to write to it via `sscanf()` will cause a crash.

Specifically, `attack()` calls `life()` (which is an infinite loop - why?) when:

- The values of 2 random numbers happen to be equal by which I think you are trying to prevent an animal attacking itself. Perhaps the function should return, or perhaps it should try again to select 2 distinct animals. Change:

  ```
   if (rnd == rnd1){life();}
  ```

  to

  ```
   if (rnd == rnd1) return;
  ```
- `creature.life` is 0 which I think indicates that the animal is dead. Again you should probably just return from the function. Change:

  ```
   if (creat.life ==0 ){life();}
  ```

  to

  ```
   if (creat.life == 0 ) return;
  ```

and the same for `creat1`.

One other suggestion, calling `system("clear")` is going to be very slow. You could just print out the ANSI escape sequence to clear the terminal:

```
char *cls = "\033[2J\033[H";    // clear screen and move cursor home
printf(cls);
```

Comment: the best solution I think would be to convert the algorithm to an iterative one (eliminate the recursion).

Comment: @bolov: I'm not sure that the recursion is intended. I think that OP is merely trying to "return" to the calling function which is `life()`.

Comment: i know the algorithm is primitive cause my knowledge of this kind of program is low and also the manage of the strings and array i just basic , teorical life need more function calls like reborn or genetic modify or else , the complete program is an attempt to made virtual life .

Comment: @MuhammadYousuf: I've made some suggestions in my answer that at least will stop your program crashing.

Comment: thanks now it work perfectly :)